# Root home is not /root on my debian?

Tags: debian, root, home

When I use `su` to get root, and then I `cd ~`

I am not on the /root, when I `ls` it shows me a Desktop file and some hidden files like .bashrc, but nothing else.

```
root@debian:~# ls -a
.  ..  .adobe  .bash_history  .bashrc  .cache  .config  Desktop  .gnome2  .gnome2_private  .local  .macromedia  .mozilla  .profile  .vim  .viminfo
```

to go to the real /root I have to `cd /` from here.

I thought that there were no `../` from `/root`, so what is this `~` ?

edit 2 :

```
xxxx@debian:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
xxxx@debian:~$ su
Password: 
root@debian:/home/xxxx# cd
root@debian:~# ls
Desktop
root@debian:~# pwd
/root
root@debian:~# cd /
root@debian:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  vmlinuz
root@debian:/# pwd
/
```

Comment: The `/` directory is not the same as `/root`.

Comment: after typing `su` what is the result of `pwd` command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaking two things that have similar names.

`root` - is also called `/` - it's the starting point of your disc. If you imagine your filesystem laid out as a tree(in mathematical sense), you will see clearly why it's called a root - it does not have an ancestor, only children.

However, `/root` is whole different thing. You can see the name differs - very little, only `/` at the beginning, but that's what changes meaning dramatically. `/root` is a directory called `root` which you can find in `/`. So, if you do:

`cd / && ls | grep root`

you will see that there is ineed a directory called `root`. And that's the directory you're mistaking for `/`. The difference is that `/root` is home directory for root user, and `/` is a root of your filesystem. You can read more about this topic [on this site](http://www.linfo.org/root.html)

Answer (score 2):

The directory `/root` is a directory called `root` at the top of the filesystem. Perhaps you are confusing the root of the filesystem `/` with the home directory for the `root` user.

Comment: so /root is not the directory containing bin,boot,dev etc... but , / is (according to my new edit )?

Comment: yes that's is `/root` is just the homedir of the user `root`

Comment: @aqww the directory `/root` is no different to a hypothetical directory `/admin`

Answer (score 1):

Normal. `su` without argument is just changing the id of the user without really loading the full requested user environment.

So basically you are just in your local user environment under root id.

If you want to really load root environment you have to do `su -` or `su -l` which will load the requested user full environment.

Comment: and im not sure why this answer got downvoted as far as im pretty sure the OP just typed `su` instead of `su -` or `su -l` which keeps the standard user configuration instead of fully loading the root environment. And im also pretty sure that the `/root` directory doesn't contains any `Desktop` directory...nor `.Adobe` hidden directory (99% of chance it's his standard user homedir)

Comment: well it seems im wrong. Just checked in my shell, just typing`su` keep you in my local user directory, but $HOME is defined to `/root`, so typing `cd ~` drives me to `/root`

Answer (score 1):

To know where you are in the directory tree, you have to type:

```
pwd
```

By the way, the root directory is /root. this is the personal directory of the root user (the superadmin if you prefer). When you type:

```
cd /
```

You are relocating your actual user at the root (the top) of the filesystem hierarchy which contains the root user directory.